# Excel: Read .dbf file from microsoft query (other sources)

Tags: vba, excel, ms-query

Enviroment: Microsoft Office 2010, Windows 10

I can not obtain this external data from my .dbf file using Microsoft Query, maybe my data source is incorrectly configured but I tried all the drivers that could handle this format, for example "Driver do Microsoft dBASE (*.dbf)", "Visual Fox Pro tables", etc. and choosed all the existing versions (III, IV and 5.0), then I get the error "imposible the access to the table x", so I'm not sure what it's not working here.

Making the connection through this tool from Excel in order to read the file is required but also VBA code are well accepted too.

This is a link to the zonas.dbf file:
https://ufile.io/vuhfk

Comment: Office 2018? Are you sure?

Comment: Sorry, I have made the correction